# NextJS 13 Metadata SVG Favicon

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Instead of `favicon.ico`, I want to use an emoji  as my icon.

```
<link rel="icon"
      href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
<text y='.9em' font-size='90'></text></svg>" />
```

But how can I do this via [Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata)?

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'Find the edge.',
}
```

It does have an icon property, but it takes a file name.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just pass in the SVG string to it and it works!

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Journey Explorer",
  description: 'Find the edge.',
  icons: "data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><text y='.9em' font-size='90'></text></svg>",
}
```